# How should I version an ASP.NET Web Site project?

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-site-project

I've got an ASP.NET Web Site project and I'd like to display a version number and publish date, but I'm not sure how best to determine these.  For example, the following code just outputs `0.0.0.0`

```
LabelVersion.Text = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Should I determine the assembly version somehow during build time and store this?  I'm using CruiseControl.Net with MSBuild.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well using the executing assembly is not neccessary a good choice as the executing assembly will be your web server. However, you could get the version off an included dll from a type that is implemented by this dll.

```
typeof(myClass).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Comment: The web site project relies on a class library project so I will just use that as the master version, getting the version number in the way you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Assembly version to be able to use it the way you describe.

Most people use the first 3 digits as manual verisons:

```
Major.Minor.Release.xxxx
```

And many people use the fourth digit for source control revision number.