# How to get asp.net website product name and version?

Tags: asp.net, web

Hopefully this is an easy one - though I don't seem to have much luck Googling the following:

Usually in an ASP.NET **Web Application** I would write - `My.Application.Info.ProductName` or `My.Application.Info.Version`, but I'm looking at an older ASP.NET **Web Site** and it doesn't have the Application option.

Does anyone know the equivalents?

Comment: What do you mean? What would the values come from?

Comment: Are you referring to the values that would be set in the *.csproj for a more current ASP.NET site? Your best bet may be getting and setting these values from the web.config.

Comment: I guess - I've not worked with the older "Web Site" project before - I always use "Web Application", is there a way to get the Product name and version (or equivalent) in the Web Site Project? - it's only for logging, but I'd rather not have to update it manually on every release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question:

[How should I version an ASP.NET Web Site project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314789/how-should-i-version-an-asp-net-web-site-project)

My solution was to use the assembly version of an assembly I included with my web site.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the name as stated in the AssemblyInfo-file? In that case you can get the name by

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName()
```

Comment: I believe the executing assembly in the case of a ASP.NET Web Site will be the web server itself - not what you want in this case.

Comment: I'm working on a project with an AssemblyInfo.cs-file in the web project, and the version in it is updated on every release...The above code outputs this version, so I would say it works :)